# Exporting Outlook Emails in Readable Format files

Tags: email, outlook

I'm using Outlook 2016 / 2010 with Microsoft Exchange account of my organization. I want to export the emails to readable format files. Examples: EML, TXT, etc.

Here are the softwares that I've tried:

> SysTools OST Convertor 5.0 - does not write From, To, Cc fields
>   correctly.
>
> Reliefjet Essentials 4.7 - requires outlook profiles (not ost) - does
>   good conversion to EML files
>
> GainTools OST Converter - takes OST files - does good conversion to
>   EML files.
>
> softaken ost file exporter - takes OST files - does good conversion to
>   EML files.

These were the effective ones. I also tried more tools which were not effective.

But all these are commercial softwares with their trials available for limited email conversion.

But are there any free softwares which can create readable files from outlook?

Comment: There is [`readpst`](http://www.five-ten-sg.com/libpst/) and [`pffexport`](https://github.com/libyal/libpff). They are Linuxistic, so may not be what you are looking for, and they do not work very well on my files, but maybe your files are different.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook can do this natively.

### Save emails as txt

1. Ctrl+click or shift-click to select multiple emails.
2. Go to File > Save as

Note: All the emails you selected are saved as a single text file, which might not be what you want.

### Save emails as csv

1. Go to File > "Open & Export" > "Import/Export"
2. Select "Export to a file"
3. Select "Comma Separated Values"
4. Select a folder to export. All of the emails in this folder will be exported.
5. Select a location to save the CSV

With the CSV export, emails are saved in one text file, with one email per row. Commas separate the fields. The body of the email appears in the second field/column. You can open CSVs in a text editor, but it will be more readable in a spreadsheet program like Excel, LibreOffice, or Google Sheets. Many programs support importing data from a CSV.

[image: A CSV file opened in Notepad, with "Word Wrap" turned off and highlighting added to show the columns]

[image: A CSV file opened in Excel, with "Wrap Text" turned on, to show how the columns are easier to read]